# Override container settings for an image in a div? Want it to fill 100% the whole div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem setting up an image in my asp.net website. I'm using the bootstrap 3,4 version. The code i have done so far is:

**Code**

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 contentpage1">
    <img src="~/images/index.jpg" class="img-responsive" />

</div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
 .contentpage1 {
background-color: white;  
}
```

I think it is because the body is inside an container class, but i'm not sure.

An image of how it looks you see here:

[image]

Here you can see the div which has a white background-color that just sticks out on the sides. I want the image to fill 100% of the div. How can i do this?

Comment: Create a demo of your output please.

Comment: Why using `background-color` instead of `background-image` then ?

Comment: I think `padding-left:0;` and `padding-right:0` will solve it.

Comment: because background-image dosen't work.. i have an image in my image folder, and if i point it to it with the URL tag it dosen't show up

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nope. Background-color is different and is not an issue. Image is rendered from HTML

Comment: @ManojKumar Humm I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the gap at sides is `col-sm-12` which adds default padding.

```css
.col-sm-12.contentpage1 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 contentpage1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x600" class="img-responsive" />

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```